# Kafka partition distribution across consumers in a consumer group

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Am I right that, at every moment of time, partition distribution across consumers in a consumer group follows the Dirichlet box principle, if number of consumers is smaller than number of partitions? I.e. if the consumer group has N consumers and a topic has M partitions and N < M, N-1 consumers got by one partition assigned to each, and the N-th consumer got M - N + 1 partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some consumer will have multiple assigned partitions, yes. It's not guaranteed to be the Nth-1 consumer that's started, or consecutive partitions assigned.